# Annotating Django querysets with a column from the first row of a reverse relation

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a `Review` model, and a `ReviewScore` ForeignKey'd to it, representing a score at a certain point in time. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    # Nothing interesting here.


class ReviewScore(models.Model):
    review = models.ForeignKey(Review)
    date = models.DateField()
    score = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-date",)
```

In my view, I wish to annotate a Review queryset with the value of `score` from the most recent row in the ReviewScore table (specifically, I do *not* want an average), so that I can sort by the most recent score given to a Review.

I've tried `.annotate(score=F("reviewscore__score"))` but this returns multiple rows; thus it returns duplicate `Review`s, each annotated with a different ReviewScore score, and using `distinct` can't cure this because Postgres requires that a `distinct` must match the ORDER BY expression.

Is this possible? Can I somehow filter or limit the results returned the foreign table with `.annotate`, or otherwise make it only annotate with the first result from the `ReviewScore` table?

Answer (score 3):

In recent Django versions, you can use [Subquery expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) in annotations:

```py
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

scores = ReviewScore.objects.filter(review=OuterRef("pk")).order_by("-date")
reviews = Review.objects.annotate(
    latest_score=Subquery(scores.values("score")[:1])
)
sorted_reviews = reviews.order_by('latest_score')
```

This way, you can be database agnostic (it works with sqlite3 for example).

Answer (score 1):

The following should work using the Postgres functionality (`distinct(*fields)`) that you were referring to:

```
Review.objects
    .annotate(score=F("reviewscore__score"), date=F("reviewscore__date"))
    .order_by('pk', '-date')  # groups by id and descending date
    .distinct('pk')
```

If you want a different display order than by `pk`, I think you would have to sort in Python because any nested filter with `pk__in` would lose the annotations.